# Why am I getting the same prediction for my Random Forest algorithm?

Tags: python, random-forest

I am trying my hand at an RF code for predicting data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

def get_results(model, X, y) :
    r2 = r2_score(y, model.predict(X))
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, model.predict(X)))
    mae = mean_absolute_error(y, model.predict(X))
    return r2, rmse, mae

df = pd.read_csv("DB_Test_1SCO2.csv")

# drop first column
df = df.drop(["Unnamed: 0"], axis=1)

# split training and testing set
X = df.iloc[:, 1:-1]
y = df.sMeOH

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# train random forest
regr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 10,
                             max_features = 15,
                             max_depth = 12,
                             random_state=0)
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(regr.predict([[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50.72,19.84,5.34,0,0,0,0,1.7,0,0,553,44.2,10000]]))
print(regr.predict([[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,19.84,5.34,0,0,0,0,1.7,0,0,553,44.2,10000]]))
```

The output for both is 61.01373333.
I could use some help with figuring out what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it, thanks!

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem into a [mre]. Then ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953). Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Random forests operate by constructing a multitude of decision trees. If I understand well, the input to the classifier is a vector of 21 values. A decision tree is a method, which separates the input into several "leaves" based on conditions from training data. Because both vectors are in 20 values the same and only one input is different, it means that this one value with this "small" (in this case) difference has no influence on the final prediction. So it is not about the wrong code. Both inputs are only too similar based on training data which makes rules in the decision trees.